# What is effective mass approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics

Currently i am studing about quantum confinement in semiconductors and came across effective mass approximation.but i am unable to understand this concept. what is the use of effective mass approximation in semiconductours.i am not a physicist so if possible please use less equations.

Advance thanks

Comment: What exactly confuses you about the concept? The more detail you give in your question, the better the answer you'll get.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky one of my doubt is why for finding energy gap of a semiconductors we need EMA..what is its importance?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from our lectures is that we like to work with free electrons, they are easier to work with than electrons in a potential and solving Schrödingers equation for them is less of a hassle.

The idea of the effective mass approximation is to look at bound electrons in a material as if they were free particles, but of a different mass. In other words, exhibiting the potential in a change of mass from **m** → **m*** rather than in a potential **V**. This is not useful directly, but if you can also afford some other approximations (such as a parabolic one, assuming this newly-expressed **m*** is constant), it makes working with approximate band-diagrams of some materials (such as silicon for example) easier.

I am no expert on this, but due to the lack of answers, I tried to post at least something. Corrections are welcome.